# Android TransactionTooLargeException after many hours test

Tags: android, android-binder, transactiontoolargeexception

I faced an issue on Samsung's devices.
After many hours of stress test, two widgets display abnormally and an ANR happened about this two widgets (cmaweather and storyalbumwidget).

Here is the trace:

> 02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728): Exception when unbinding
>   service
>   com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.cmaweather/.SurfaceWidgetWeather
>   02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException 02-11 08:38:00.219
>   W/ActivityManager(  728):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native
>   Method) 02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleUnbindService(ApplicationThreadNative.java:880)
>   02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.removeConnectionLocked(ActiveServices.java:1365)
>   02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.unbindServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:639)
>   02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.unbindService(ActivityManagerService.java:13374)
>   02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:824)
>   02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2136)
>   02-11 08:38:00.219 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 02-11 08:38:00.219
>   W/ActivityManager(  728):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native
>   Method) 02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728): Exception when
>   starting service
>   com.sec.android.widgetapp.ap.hero.cmaweather/.SurfaceWidgetWeather
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException 02-11 08:38:00.239
>   W/ActivityManager(  728):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native
>   Method) 02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleCreateService(ApplicationThreadNative.java:857)
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.realStartServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:1111)
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.bringUpServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:1034)
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.bindServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:534)
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.bindService(ActivityManagerService.java:13367)
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:814)
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2136)
>   02-11 08:38:00.239 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 02-11 08:38:00.239
>   W/ActivityManager(  728):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native
>   Method) 02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728): Exception when
>   unbinding service
>   com.samsung.android.app.storyalbumwidget/.StoryAlbumWidget 02-11
>   08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException 02-11 08:38:00.249
>   W/ActivityManager(  728):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native
>   Method) 02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleUnbindService(ApplicationThreadNative.java:880)
>   02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.removeConnectionLocked(ActiveServices.java:1365)
>   02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.unbindServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:639)
>   02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.unbindService(ActivityManagerService.java:13374)
>   02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:824)
>   02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2136)
>   02-11 08:38:00.249 W/ActivityManager(  728):  at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388) 02-11 08:38:00.249
>   W/ActivityManager(  728):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native
>   Method)

I know that TransactionTooLargeException is because of a too large data for the transaction.
But I don't know why this Exception only happened after many hours of stress test.
In stress test, we just open some app again and again.

Does anyone have any idea?
How could I check this issue?

Comment: What are you sending in the intent to open this widgets?